# Telegram bot doesnt answer

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

This is code of my bot in PHP, but it doesnt answer. What should I do? Here's the PHP error log :

```
 [24-Sep-2018 09:06:29 UTC] PHP Warning:       file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot694EMvJayx1zD-J3FPyKPfRlGka0  /sendMessage?chat_id=110***01&amp;text=hellhAkbarixyzhMohammad Hosein): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
in /home/xcqcctmm/public_html/BOT/getnewsir.php on line 22
```

The code is :

```
<?php 
$token = '692******1zD-J3FPyKPfRlGka0';

// read incoming info and grab the chatID 
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$telegram = urldecode ($json);
$results = json_decode($telegram); 
$message = $results->message;
$text = $message->text;
$chat = $message->chat;
$user_id = $chat->id;

$username = $chat->username;
$first_name = $chat->first_name;

//send reply

$answer = "hello".$user_id . "h" . $username . "h" . $first_name;
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.      $user_id .'&text='.$answer;
file_get_contents($url); 

?>
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram's API returns `400 Bad Request`, which could be caused by any of the following:

- `FIRSTNAME_INVALID`: The first name is invalid
- `LASTNAME_INVALID`: The last name is invalid
- `PHONE_NUMBER_INVALID`: The phone number is invalid
- `PHONE_CODE_HASH_EMPTY`: phone_code_hash is missing
- `PHONE_CODE_EMPTY`: phone_code is missing
- `PHONE_CODE_EXPIRED`: The confirmation code has expired
- `API_ID_INVALID`: The api_id/api_hash combination is invalid
- `PHONE_NUMBER_OCCUPIED`: The phone number is already in use
- `PHONE_NUMBER_UNOCCUPIED`: The phone number is not yet being used
- `USERS_TOO_FEW`: Not enough users (to create a chat, for example)
- `USERS_TOO_MUCH`: The maximum number of users has been exceeded (to create a chat, for example)
- `TYPE_CONSTRUCTOR_INVALID`: The type constructor is invalid
- `FILE_PART_INVALID`: The file part number is invalid
- `FILE_PARTS_INVALID`: The number of file parts is invalid
- `FILE_PART_Х_MISSING`: Part X (where X is a number) of the file is missing from storage
- `MD5_CHECKSUM_INVALID`: The MD5 checksums do not match
- `PHOTO_INVALID_DIMENSIONS`: The photo dimensions are invalid
- `FIELD_NAME_INVALID`: The field with the name `FIELD_NAME` is invalid
- `FIELD_NAME_EMPTY`: The field with the name `FIELD_NAME` is missing
- `MSG_WAIT_FAILED`: A waiting call returned an error

Unfortunately, you have to debug which one causing the actual error.

[Source](https://core.telegram.org/api/errors#400-bad-request)